# How to Resolve Recaptcha Aggregate Timeout Error in node js

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

when i used Recaptcha v3 on Login routes it shows me the given error Sometimes it verified the Recaptcha Token and after 10 mints it shows this error in my console. My code for verification of token is

```
const verifyCaptchaUrl = `https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${process.env.LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_KEY}&response=${req.body.recaptcha}`;
const response = await request.get({
  url: verifyCaptchaUrl,
});

const body = JSON.parse(response);

if (body.success) {
  delete req.body.recaptcha;
  console.log("Captcha Verification Successful");
  next();
} else {
  return next(new AppError("Error in ReCaptcha Verification", 400));
}
```

I was expecting that it verified my reCaptcha token but it won't please help me to fix this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsOS4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlxql.png)

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you